# How to merge 3 video in one screen with blur

Tags: ffmpeg

How to merge 3 videos on one screen, with blur on 2 of videos

I already wrote code and it's look likes this

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi input1.avi input2.avi -filter_complex "[0:v]gblur=sigma=6.5[v10];[1:v][v11];[2:v]gblur=sigma=6.5[v12];[v10][v11][v12]hstack=inputs=3[v]" -map "[v]" output.avi
```

And i get error like this

```
    o such filter: ''
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

What i should do ?

Answer (score 0):

You omitted the `-i` before some of the inputs and you don't need `[1:v][v11]`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i input1.avi -i input2.avi -filter_complex "[0:v]gblur=sigma=6.5[v10];[2:v]gblur=sigma=6.5[v12];[v10][1:v][v12]hstack=inputs=3[v]" -map "[v]" output.avi
```